# Plotting Elliptic Curve over Finite Field in Maple

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, maple

Not sure if I might be in the wrong section, but I am looking for guidance on how to plot an elliptic curve over a finite field in Maple. I have tried looking it up but only getting good results for Matlab (which I do not have access to).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of plot do you want to see? The rational points of an elliptic curve over a finite field is a finite set, so what kind of visualization are you looking for?

Comment: Do you have access to sage? You can plot elliptic curves on sage as well.

Comment: What does it mean to "plot" something over a finite field? You can plot the real-number analog of the curve. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm trying to create a plot that looks like a scatter graph. I have tried unsuccessfully to use Sage.